# Saving raster to jpeg with rioxarray

Tags: jpg, rioxarray

I wanted to save a raster (1 band) file as a jpeg with:

```
xarray.rio.to_raster(save_path, compress='JPEG',
                         photometric='YCBCR' if xarray.sizes['band'] == 3 else None,
                         num_threads='all_cpus', tiled=True, dtype='uint8')
```

The nodata value originally is 55537.
I get the error:

error:  rasterio._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError: MissingRequired:TIFF directory is missing required "StripOffsets" field

I was wondering, why I get an Error for GTIFF while saving a JPEG, therefore I added the parameter:
driver='JPEG', which didn't change anything.

```
I already save the raster with:
    xarray.rio.to_raster(save_path, compress='zstd', zstd_level=1, num_threads='all_cpus', tiled=True, dtype='uint8', predictor=2)
```

and didn't encounter any error. What cold cause the error?

Comment: Is the input file a geotiff?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `driver="JPEG"` unless you have rioxarray 0.2+ and rasterio 1.2+ that has driver detection based on the file extension.

EDIT: http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/man/TIFFReadDirectory.3tiff.html

Based on the link above, it seems that the input file is missing tags required to read the file.